# undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass image base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting

> NoMethodError in BuyTagsController#index
>   undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (`buy_tags_controller.rb` around line #18):

```
  eco_producer.nreduction = eco_value['nreduction']
  str  = eco_value['image']
  eco_producer.image = Base64.decode64(str)
  eco_producer.save
end
```

Application Trace:

```
    .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/base64.rb:58:in `decode64'
    app/controllers/buy_tags_controller.rb:18:in `block in index'
    app/controllers/buy_tags_controller.rb:13:in `each'
    app/controllers/buy_tags_controller.rb:13:in `index'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
```

Comment: The problem is that `eco_value['image']` is nil.  How are you setting this hash?  Try logging the value of `eco_value`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>> Base64.decode64(nil)
    NoMethodError: undefined method `unpack' for nil:NilClass
      from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/base64.rb:58:in `decode64'
      from (irb):7
      from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
      from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
      from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
      from C:/workspace/projects/YBWebFramework/director2/script/rails:11:in `require'
      from C:/workspace/projects/YBWebFramework/director2/script/rails:11:in `<top (required)>'
      from -e:1:in `load'
      from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Fix this issue. Have a check and don't pass nil to decode. Something like if str .present?  then execute next line

Comment: Actually for the development I was testing without the data validations.. so I thought that once the API data has been imported into the database after that I will apply validations and I just forgot to check that the image has null values  .. Thanks..!!